# A Comment is causing code to display incorrectly (CSS/Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, comments

This is one of the strangest things I have encountered. A *COMMENT* (or lack thereof) is causing the output to change. See this below, notice the `<!--` and `-->` in the middle.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 vertical-center">
                <h2>
                    TEST
                    <small>
                        <span>Test</span>
                    </small>
                </h2>
            </div><!--
        --><div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 vertical-center">
                <h2 class="text-right skip-pause-buttons">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

If I have it there, it displays okay. If I remove it, the code stops displaying correctly. See this image:

[image]

The top case is WITHOUT the comment (for some reason it displays on two lines).
The bottom case is WITH the comment (displays correctly).

What on earth is going on?

---

**EDIT:** I just noticed if the  is on the same line as the  (even without the comment) it displays correctly. But as soon as it's on a different line, it stops displaying correctly.

Comment: Are the divs surrounding the comments `inline-block`?

Comment: How do you mean? The only thing surrounding the code above is `<body ng-controller="MyController">`?

Comment: Either or both the divs before and after the comment i.e. `<div class="col-xs-6...`

Comment: I made a mistake with the code in the original message. I've fixed this now so you can see that there were no other div blocks

Comment: Ah... you're right. `display: inline-block;` is on the vertical-center css. What should I do to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The comments are used to remove any whitespace between the two elements (you can achieve the same results with float left)

Usually is better to use grid classes only for grid purpose.

Comment: I've never heard of this happening before. So strange. So where should I put float: left to overcome this?

Comment: @b85411 what's the style associate with the class vertical-center? Bootstrap grid have already the float property in the cols, unless you have changed/overridden that property. Try to remove that class, or add a div inside the col-* and add that class to that div. Just saw your other comment, you have to remove that class from the col-*, adding a child div with that class will solve your problem (or you can keep the comment tags)